# How to iterate sub elements of <ul> in Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium

I am trying to iterate `<li>` items of `<ul>` object in Selenium with C#. I am very new to it and trying to find a easy way write a code for my test project.

here is my sample html code, I would like to access those links below...

```
<ul class="list-menu">
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li><a class="head" href="/seramik-banyo-urunleri">Seramik Banyo &#220;r&#252;nleri</a></li>
           <li><a href="/seramik-banyo-urunleri/lavabo">Lavabo</a></li>
           <li><a href="/seramik-banyo-urunleri/klozet">Klozet</a></li>
```

my c# code is like below

```
IList<IWebElement> results = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='list-menu']/li/lu/li"));
```

but it doesn't get the links. what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the XPath expression, replace:

```
//div[@class='list-menu']/li/lu/li
```

with:

```
//div[@class='list-menu']/li/ul/li
```

Or, you can use a more compact *CSS selector* instead:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".list-menu > li > ul > li"));
```

where `>` means a direct parent-child relationship.

Comment: oh my god, thank you very much. what a silly mistake. also, thank for the last example. it is much easier to code like the last one

Comment: @ayilmaz - I also make silly mistakes like this. Its always good to check your xpath or other locators first. You can see this in the stack trace.